# return type for `input_iterator::operator*`?

Tags: c++, iterator, dereference

I'm doing an input iterator wrapper for a `QSqlQuery` (for traversing rows and constructing a new class type object for each row), and I want to know what must be the returned type of `operator*`.

According to `cppreference` in the [input iterator concept description](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/InputIterator), the returned type of `*i` must be:

> reference, convertible to value_type

and curiously, I'm in doubt about if that comma `,` represent an `or` or and `and` ("reference to value_type or/and convertible to value_type"), because in my case, I construct a new object (whose type is a class template parameter) when calling `operator*`. Consequently, I cannot return a reference.

To match the input iterator "concept", can I return the object by value?

Comment: Usually an iterator fetches the new value when you increment it, and stores it inside itself, and then returns a reference to that when you dereference it.

Comment: The think is, since `value_type` is a template, I delegate its construction to the class itself (a static member function of `value_type` called `fetch`, receiving the row, and returning the new object).  Since I don't know how expensive that object is, if the object is assignable or not, and so on, I don't know how to "store" the object inside the iterator class without impossing new requirements to `value_type` or using `new` (which could be unnecesary for little objects).

Answer (score 2):

`iterator_traits<>` must define 5 types, one of which is `reference`, hence the comma. You can return by value; it's only fair to do so for `const_iterator`, thought: for non-const, you cannot modify the original. I guess this is ok here as you have an sql query. In this case you do `typedef value_type reference;` inside `iterator_traits<T>`.